# Django queryset filter from two models

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my Django app I have two model and I don't know how to do a query for select the right record. This is the code:

```
class tab1 (models.Model):
    id_tab1 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class tab2 (models.Model):
    id_tab1 = models.ForeignKey(tab1)
    type = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to select the tab1 records that have tab2.type equal to some condition. How can I do this in Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
your_queryset = tab1.objects.filter(tab2__type=value)
```

See the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
In a few words: you can span relationships either way (i.e. from each end of a foreign key).
The **condition** is specified in the named argument to filter(). The one I suggested above is the simplest one (i.e. equality), but there are quite a few more (e.g. startswith, contains, etc). Please read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have values 1,2 stored for the field `type`. The following illustrates the one way of achieving your need for `type=1`.

```
filtered_objs = tab1.objects.filter(type=1)
tab2.objects.filter( tab1__in=filtered_objs)
```

Comment: You may improve your answer with some description of what does what, how it is intended to be used and maybe a link to the documentation ? (I suspect there's a typo on the second line too)